# how can I use one custom adapter class for multiple screens in android?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-adapter

How can I use same adapter class for multiple screen(different task) under same project.

**Tasks are:-**
Suppose:-

- one screen has Grid view image with text
- second Screen List View only text
- same adapter for drawer Layout

is possible to use same custom adapter for every classes???

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: refer this http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to create the same adapter in that case. Maintain different Adapters for that, Because in the future You would need different animation for both or some specific changes.for list/grid in that case you will end up writing lot of `if-else` in `getView()`, that will make your listview/gridview slower

Answer (score 0):

Best way is, you need to create separate `CustomAdapter` for both . If you have same type of layout means you can use same `Adapter`. otherwise create new one